# How can I view the traceback of an Xcode linker error?

Tags: xcode

I'm getting an `Apple Mach-O Linker Error` in Xcode. This is what shows in the sidebar: [image]

When I try to click on the errors, nothing happens. How can I see the traceback so I can try to debug this?

Comment: Normally there should be more information about the issue you clicked on in the main window. Are they visibly?

Comment: @maximilian_cs No, nothing happens when I them.

Comment: Try restarting Xcode and your Mac. Normally there is a lot of additional information in the main window. You see an exact error message and can google the solution to it.

Comment: @maximilian_cs Tried it, still not working. This works for me for things like syntax errors, but not linker errors.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing